# What is method of targeting html input that clone using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image: Form Example]

```
 $('.fileupload').change(function(event){
            var fd = new FormData();
            var files = $(this)[0].files;
            var a = this.id;
            console.log(a);
            var data_inp = 'data_' + a;
            // Check file selected or not
                if(files.length > 0 ){
                   fd.append('file',files[0]);
                   $.ajax({
                      url: 'uploadtest.php',
                      type: 'post',
                      data: fd,
                      contentType: false,
                      processData: false,
                      success: function(response){
                         console.log(response);
                         $("#data_inp").val(response);
                        
                      },
                   });
                }else{
                   alert("Please select a file.");
                }
               
            });
```

just want to give value in input that clone by using the "add more button", it's working fine with the normal form once I clone from and try with other than it's working with clone input.

Comment: You have a missing qout: `$("#data_inp▶️"◀️).val(response);`

Comment: sorry i have forgot to type that but that's not the issue actually I have clone that form using plus button so due to that change call is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try by calling that clone form other PHP file using ajax.

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $.ajax({url: "you_clone_file.php", success: function(result){
        $("#your_form_div").html(result);
    }});
});
```